# Android Studio: Does not show all errors immediately

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, ide

I'm coming from Eclipse and I am used to immediate error reporting over the whole project.

Lets say I have this function:

```
public void test() {
   //Do something
}
```

and I change it to

```
public void test(String someString) {
   //Do something
}
```

Then eclipse would immediately highlight all classes in the project explorer, that call test() without also passing a string.

Android studio does not. It only shows it, when I happen to open such a file. Ofcource, when I compile, I will also get an error, but also only for the first file he tried to compile and failed and not for all.

I am currently in a big refactoring and this is really tedious. Compile - wait - fix one file - start over...

Am I missing someting? Not even Analyze/Inspect code... does the trick.

PS: I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3 with latest updates (24.02.2017)

Answer (score 2):

Too late for you by now, but for future reference to yourself:

- Instead of changing  the signature of the method by adding an argument to it "manually", right click on the method, go to `Refactor`, go to `Change Signature`, in the `Parameters` tab click on the plus icon and add the parameter there. Now right click on the method again and select `Find Usages`. That will show you where you're calling the new refactored method and you can fix your code quickly.

However, **to answer your question**, you can see where all your errors are. Just go to `Build` and rebuild your project via `Rebuild Project` and then go the left hand side of Android Studio and change the project view to `Problems`

[image: Android Studio Problems]

See if that helps

Comment: As I said. Rebuilding only highlits the first problem he stumbles uppon. else this would already solve all my problems. :(

About the other suggestion. I know that, but this is not how I roll. I Refactured a lot of function in one file in one go. I didn't want to jump all around the code for each function I changed. I wanted to change all function to accept a new parameter in this class, then look at the fallout and decide if it is worth it and quickly go through all places that I have to adjust.

Comment: And it is not too late ;). I was annoyed for some time now, it happens often for my way of coding. I don't hesitate when it's about refactoring code to clean things up. So I fear this is a limit of Android Studio for now :( If I would open all files I would get the result I want... Hope they implement this like it was in eclipse. Miss it.

Comment: Any solution to this?